# CreateProcess Failed; code 193. 1% is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to install OpenJDK 11 and IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2. but I get the error below. I also experienced the same issue when I was installing Android Studio. Please help. How can I resolve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIFhv.png)

Comment: Use IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. It has an option to download and install JDK for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 has a feature to automatically [download and configure the JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#manage_sdks) for you. If JDK installer doesn't work for you, it may be an option.